# Unable to replicate the Carbon design angular example on https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter

Tags: angularjs, carbon-design-system, carbon-components

I updated the carbon design angular example given on the following Github page:
`https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-angular-starter`

to be compatible with Angular 16. And running it with `npm start`, I got the following output:

```
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /home/carbon-angular-starter/node_modules/carbon-components-angular/fesm2020/carbon-components-angular-datepicker.mjs depends on 'flatpickr/dist/plugins/rangePlugin'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

I added

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash" 
......
```

as proposed in the 'warning logs'. Checking the output on localhost, I got the image shown below. After trying other examples, I still got the same issue - the expected output were not displayed as seen in the tutorials. I do not know why this happens, [image: output] when using carbon design angular examples. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.